# Cannot remove spacing between objects

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

Please view the code and gaps between the images shown here:
http://jsfiddle.net/uyVZj/2/

In Firefox / IE it automatically makes a 5px margin in between each image.
In Safari it makes a 10px margin between each image.

How do I control this margin between the images in these two browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove width fro your `li` because the width of the image in `160px` & you define width in `li 166px`

Check http://jsfiddle.net/uyVZj/5/

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is your inline styles. `width: 166px` is too long. http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/uyVZj/3/

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem might be in that you're using multiple CSS mechanisms to control the same aspect when rendering the `li` tags (display, position/left and float). Try reducing it to just one (or more if necessary) and see if that brings some consistency.

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GoranMottram/teHk3/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/uyVZj/6/

```
I have removed the width from `li` tags and added style="display:block"
```

on anchor tags